# Would my Audio LED display circuit work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, led, audio, circuit-design, filter

[image: Circuit Diagram]
[image: Sweep]

Would this circuit work? It's supposed to display the frequencies of the audio signal connected using LEDs by driving them with an LM358 Op-Amp.

Edit: fixed the reverse polarity of U7

Edit 2: I made a sweep of the frequency response of the filter, seems to work

Comment: If each of your LEDs is at 10mA, then the max power of this arrangement is >3W, which is quite a bit of heat.

Comment: @BeB00 the LEDs would be at around 6mA each

Comment: I suggest simulating one branch of your circuit and examining the results.

Comment: What is the nature of the audio input? What is the expected ac voltage, and is there an offset?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the ac voltage would go up to 5v; what do you mean offset? between the audio signal getting fed in and displaying?

Comment: Conceptually I think it's solid. Two issues I do see: If all 5 LEDs are on at 6mA, that's 30mA - most opamps can's supply that much current. Secondly, you're not rectifying the audio so the LEDs will only turn on at the positive peak of the waveform so the LED on duty cycle is fairly low - it will be hard to get much brightness.

Comment: @td127 Alright, thanks! I'll consider adding a full bridge rectifier at the input

Comment: To clarify, you would have to individually rectify your filtered signals, not the common input signal.

Comment: Oh, there's another thing. You have a single +12V rail - that will make it trickier. If you don't have a minus rail too then your incoming audio will want to be AC-coupled to the midpoint, +6V. Your opamp output will then idle at +6V, with AC swinging around that point, and your LEDs will all be stuck on. Why don't you decide if you still want to use a single 12V rail or introduce a minus rail too - the solution will depend heavily on that.

Comment: @td127 Would it work if I placed an electrolytic capacitor and then I rectified the voltage?

Comment: Your audio filters will only do what you want them to do on real audio inputs. If you rectify the signal first you're severely altering the frequency spectrum. So you need to apply any rectification or other level detection to the post-filter audio signals.

Comment: YouTube video required ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too much happening in the comments so I'll present a total back-of-the-napkin proposal, completely untested, but what could go wrong?

I think your overall concept is reasonable – it just needs a few tweaks.

First, the incoming audio is an AC signal swinging around ground, say +2V to -2V. A circuit with no negative supply can’t directly deal with those negative swings so we have to convert it to a positive-only signal.

And while we’re at it we’ll add gain such that the output of the first opamp stage has a maximum clean swing when presented with a maximum input swing.

With the circuit below, we have one opamp generate a clean +6V reference that we’ll use as the midpoint for our audio signals.

The audio is AC-coupled so that it swings around +6V at the opamp input. Some gain is added such that the output swings as much as it can (to within about 1V of its rails). The gain of this stage is 1 + R2/R1. Adjust so that maximum input yields maximum 10V output swing.

[image]

That 10V signal can now go into all your filter stages.
The output of each will be a clean signal swinging around +6V.

[image]

Now we want to convert this to something that drives the LED string so let’s take a look at your scheme:

[image]

Let’s assume each LED drops 2V when on and sucks 4mA. I know you said 6mA but 6 * 5 = 30mA is too much for normal opamps. Even 4 * 5 = 20mA is pushing it. Either buy a beefy opamp or more efficient LEDs (some are bright at 3mA).

So the turn-on levels for the LEDs are something like:

+2.8V LED1

+3.5V LED2

+4.1V LED3

+4.7V LED4

+5.3V LED5

We need to convert that filtered audio AC signal that’s swinging around +6V to a DC voltage that starts at about +2.5V with no audio present, and can reach +5.3V with a hot signal.

Here’s a crazy circuit, legal in most states, that can do that with one opamp and no diodes:

[image]

The audio gain is R4/R3 and can be adjusted to achieve desired level.

What R5 is doing is biasing the output down to be centered around 2.5V but since the opamp is limited in its negative swing to about +1V the signal gets rectified.

The output bias level is:
6 – ((6/R5)*R4)

We don’t care about the rectified half. Now we just syphon off the top with a peak detector.

[image]

You’ll probably want to adjust that +2.5V bias a little higher to overcome the peak detector diode drop – ideally it’s set to be just below the level where the first LED comes on.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Very much appreciated.

Comment: So the circuit would end up looking something like this? https://i.imgur.com/OA3hIr0.png

Comment: Close! Increase your R2, R29, R32 to 10K or more. You can't combine the 2nd and 3rd opamp in the signal path into one (U1): the audio input needs to go to the + input and the next stage adds the offset. Increase R31 to achieve the desired slow-ish discharge rate of your peak detector, probably more in the 100K range. I assume those potentiometers are temporary, just to find the right values. In the real circuit they can be fixed resistors. Use first stage U7 to get max signal but be careful not to add too much: a clipped input will add harmonics and be visible in your meter.